# Can i get the template parent data context in the event function?

Tags: events, meteor

I'd love to get my hands on a templates data context.
Can I do something like this?

```
'click .newContext': function(event, template) {
    var template_parent = template.parent();
    var parent_data = template_parent.data;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Template.parentData(0)`, the argument defines how deep you want to go, if you pass none, 0 is the default. Check the documentation on this: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata

Comment: 1 is the default, that should return the direct parent (if you use dynamic templates this is actually not true (the direct parent context is in level 4 or so)). 0 will give you the current context.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if you're trying to get the parent's data context you should be able to use the [parentData()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata) method on the Template instance. You probably don't even need that second template parameter.

```
'click .newContext': function(event) {
    var parent_data = Template.parentData();
}
```