# How to get Parent object for array nested object children | MeteorJs - Astronomy

Tags: javascript, meteor, nested, meteor-blaze

I'm using [MeteorJs](https://www.meteor.com/) with [Astronomy](http://astronomy.jagi.io/nested-fields) for object validation.

This is my `Users class` :

```
Emails = Astro.Class({
  name: 'Emails',
  fields: {
    address: {
      type: 'string',
      validator: [
        Validators.required(),
        Validators.email()
      ]
    },
    verified: {
      type: 'boolean',
      validator: Validators.required(),
    }
  }
})
Users = Astro.Class({
  name: 'Users',
  collection: Meteor.users,
  fields: {
    emails: {
      type: 'array',
      nested: 'Emails',
      default: function() {
        return [];
      }
    },
  }
})
```

Now, on Template JS file, I receive event from Blaze template when user change emails, but `this` is linked to email object, and not user one. Who can I get the user object on email change event ?

**HTML**

```
{{#each emails}}
  <input type="email" name="address-{{@index}}" value="{{address}}" data-email-idx="{{@index}}">
{{/each}}
```

**JS**

```
Template.userForm.events({
  'change input[type=email]': function (event) {
    var email = this;
    var field = event.currentTarget;
    let email_idx = field.getAttribute('data-email-idx')
    email.set('address', field.value)

    // let user = {...}?
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talk to Astronomy owner, and he say it's not possible right now. So, I'm closing subject.

[Git Issue](https://github.com/jagi/meteor-astronomy/issues/259)

Answer (score 0):

`user = Template.parentData();`

Related question: [Can i get the template parent data context in the event function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956647/can-i-get-the-template-parent-data-context-in-the-event-function)

You can also access the parent data context in the HTML by using `{{../parent_field}}`.

Comment: I'm not talking about Template context on Blaze, but Parent context on Astronomy Validator